# Determine whether the given map $\phi$ is an isomorphism of the first binary structure with the second.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Determine whether the given map $\phi$ is an isomorphism of the first binary structure with the second.

$\langle ℤ,+\rangle$ with $\langle ℤ,+\rangle$ where $\phi(n)=-n$ for $n$ an element of $ℤ$

I know in order to prove two sets are isomorphic they must be:
i) $1$-$1$ $f(\phi1)=f(\phi2)$ provided $\phi1=\phi2$
ii) onto: every element in the domain has a pre-image
iii) homomorphic $f(\phi1+\phi2)=f(\phi1)*f(\phi2)$

I am just confused how to prove this when the sets are the same. Wouldn't they automatically be isomorphic?

Answer (score 1):

Condition (i) should be

> If $\phi(x)=\phi(y)$ then $x=y$

Condition (iii) should be

> $\phi(x+y)=\phi(x)+\phi(y)$

Now, can you prove that $-x=-y$ implies $x=y$?

Can you prove that $-(x+y)=(-x)+(-y)$?

What about surjectivity? Hint: it's easy.

Comment: do I just pick random numbers for x and y that are in the set?

Comment: No, you pick "arbitrary" ones.

Comment: @Lil No! You must prove it *for all* of them; so let them be variables.

Comment: alright so for proving it is 1-1 I have: let x1,x2 be elements of ℤ. f(x1)=f(x2) but what values do I substitute in for the function? Is it just -(x1)=-(x2)?

Comment: @Lil The function here is $\phi$, not $f$. And, yes, $\phi(x_1)=-x_1$.

Comment: ok, sorry I am very new to this. So for showing it is onto how do I show that every element in the codomain has a pre-image. I want n to map onto -n? So I can let b be an element of -n?

Comment: @Lil Just think that $\phi(-n)=n$.